# Ruby on Rails, Showing the hashmap array?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, hashmap, railscasts

I was wondering is there a way to show the hash map array? I'm not sure if its the right terminology? But I wanted to see the columns from the database to see if I'm calling the correct hash keys.

For instance,

```
created on <%= link_to activity.trackable.list.name, activity.trackable.list %>
```

I'm not sure if I'm calling the correct names, if I'm getting undefined method? If I need to see if there's a key for `.name` or `.list`. I would like to see the array of `activity.trackable` if there's such thing?

This code is coming from a tutorial in [rails cast #407](http://railscasts.com/episodes/407-activity-feed-from-scratch)

Comment: This is what you want: https://github.com/ctran/annotate_models

Comment: No, you don't... You can just look in the schema file, why pollute all of your models with some quick-to-become-outdated comments?

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like:

```
p activity.trackable.columns
```

or

```
p activity.trackable.columns_hash
```

or

```
p activity.trackable.column_names
```

if you want to see more, you could do

```
p activity.trackable.methods
```

or

```
p activity.trackable.respond_to?( :something )
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend installing the `awesome_print` gem

then in `rails console` you can inspect objects easily

```
ap activity.trackable

# or

ap Activity.new
```

see

- https://github.com/michaeldv/awesome_print
- http://www.rubyinside.com/awesome_print-a-new-pretty-printer-for-your-ruby-objects-3208.html
- https://rubygems.org/gems/awesome_print

OR if you are using postgres you can do

```
psql your_db_development -c "\d activities"

# lists all columns on database table and their types
```